# Anything like AutoLayout for Processing?

Tags: android, mobile, autolayout, processing

So I'm making a game for `Android` using `Processing` but I'm having trouble with my buttons not being in the same position whenever the size of the screen changes, and I'm aware that you can use `AutoLayout`, but I'm not sure how to include that into `Processing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoLayout seems to be an iOS thing.

If you're asking if you can use an Android layout inside Processing, the answer is basically no. Processing is its own component, so unless you're adding Android components (er, Views) to the Processing component, then it doesn't make sense to use an Android layout inside Processing. You'd do it the other way around and use Processing inside an Android layout- but I believe Processing is its own Activity, so you're out of luck there too.

How are you creating your buttons? Are they Android components? Are you handling the drawing of the buttons yourself in Processing code? Are you using a Processing GUI library?

I assume you're drawing the buttons yourself inside of Processing, in which case you're going to have to do the resizing yourself. **Draw the buttons based on the width and height**, like I've mentioned in your previous questions.

Processing really isn't designed to build GUI applications that contain controls like buttons. You can fake something pretty easily, and there are libraries that help (not sure if they work on Android though), but once you get into layouts and different screen sizes, you really should use a real GUI library (in this case, standard Android).

Comment: Hey man, I'm very glad you're answering my questions, another one... If that's alright :) How would I implement In-App purchases in my game? is editing the .xml file the only thing I can do, is there something I can do inside of Processing?

Comment: You're trying to do stuff that goes a bit outside the scope of Processing. You really might consider switching to standard Android.

Comment: Would there be any way or smoothly transition from processing to standard android?